# Google calendar api v3 java authentication

Tags: email, authentication, passwords, google-calendar-api

I'm initialize in Google calendar API in java language and I search how to create authentication function or access to calendar from my app, and more.

How can I authenticate with an email and password for example?

Cumps

Comment: You don't use Login and password check Oauth2. https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2   Welcome to stack please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: My application aims to import and export the phonebook of a user who will have your email address and password associated. I know nothing about you! Would only be necessary that this user uses up their login data to sync!

Comment: in order to access a users Google Calendar data your application must be authenticated.  This requires Oauth2.

Comment: How can I do this? I have searched and have not found a solution for that!

Comment: developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2

Comment: I think I understand more or less the logic of running!
But google does not provide sample projects? To see if I consego best things interconnect.

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to create a link to the google calendar!

But I don't understand how I can create calendar events and other emails?